# YAHOO Event.stopEvent

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

I am trying to prevent JavaScript events from continuing to propagate, using YUI.  The following is some minimal HTML and some minimal JavaScript which demonstrates the problem:

HTML:

```
<a href="#foo" onClick="fooClickTest()" id="foo">foo</a>&nbsp;
<a href="#bar" id="bar">bar</a>&nbsp;
```

JavaScript:

```
function fooClickTest(e) {
    alert('fooClickTest');
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener('bar', 'click', barClickTest1);
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener('bar', 'click', barClickTest2);
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener('bar', 'click', barClickTest3);
    YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
}

function barClickTest1(e) {
    alert('barClickTest1');
    YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
}

function barClickTest2(e) {
    alert('barClickTest2');
    YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(e);
    YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(e);
// Also tried:
//  YAHOO.util.Event.stopPropagation(e);
// and:
//        if (e.stopPropagation) {
//            e.stopPropagation();
//        } else {
//            e.cancelBubble = true;
//        }
}
```

What I expect to happen is that the user can click on `foo` to add the three-click handlers, and then click on `bar`.  Then, the user will see TWO alerts, `barClickTest1` and `barClickTest2`.  Instead, all three alerts occur.  The `YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(e)` does not do what I expect, which is to stop the event propagating out to `barClickTest3`.

I have tested my code in Firefox 3.0.7 and in Safari 3.2.1.  As you can see above, I have also tried `YAHOO.util.Event.stopPropagation(e)` and `e.stopPropagation()`.  None of them did the trick.

This is obviously a contrived example, though it does demonstrate the problem.  In the real solution, I will only prevent event propagation if some conditions are met.

Is my understanding of JavaScript's events simply messed up?  How do I accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't working as you expected because:

- [`YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault()`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_preventDefault) just tells the browser not to perform the default action associated with the element, in this case, navigating to the `href` attribute on the anchor.
- [`YAHOO.util.Event.stopPropagation()`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_stopPropagation) cancels the event bubbling and triggering event handlers on parent elements.
- [`YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent()`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_stopEvent) just calls `preventDefault` and `stopEvent`.

Without writing extra code there is no way to prevent certain event listeners on a single element from firing, and even if you could you couldn't be guaranteed the order the event listeners would be fired in.

You'll need to rewrite your code as a single event handler in order to be able to control if the code associated with your third click handler will execute.

Comment: Thank you.  You clearly explained why my expectations were mistaken.  Sucks, but what can you do?  By the way, I can guarantee the order the event listeners are fired in, our framework handles that, possibly for limited definitions of 'guarantee'.